# User Input with special character

Tags: batch-file

I'm currently using `set /P input =` to get the users input for a batch script.

My problem now is that it is very likely for them to use the `&` character.

Is there any way to get user input containing these special characters?

Comment: this is the wrong question: you CAN `set /p` a variable with `&` (try `set /p x=`, input `a&b`, then verify with `set x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  Use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`, then refer to your input variable as `!input!` whenever needed.  Enclosing your `"var=prompt: "` string in quotations is always good practice, too.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /P "data=Enter a string to test: "
echo(!data!
```

If you run that and enter a string with an ampersand, it gets echoed without being evaluated.

(Note about using `echo(!data!` rather than `echo !data!`: That's just a way to prevent a user entry of `/?` from breaking things.)